# Change chart height without resizing plotArea

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am trying to resize an excel chart with VBA.

Is it possible to change `ActiveChart.ChartArea.Height` without affecting the size of the `PlotArea`? Whenever I attempt to change the chart height it looks like the plot area is automatically resized, which is an undesired outcome.

I have tried the following sequence, when downsizing a graph:

1. Changing `plotarea` to fixed desired height;
2. Changing `chart` height to fixed desired height;
3. Changing `plotarea` to fixed desired height;

This sequence does not yield expected results, as **(1)** the `chart` is not changed to specified height, and **(2)** the `plotarea` height is output correctly, but its positioning within the chart (`.InsideTop`) has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next way of dealing with a chart dimensions. The scenario involves the next process: firstly memorizing the PlotArea dimensions (Height/Width), then play with the chart (Object) dimensions, reset the PlotArea ones and set its Position to Automatic. Excel tries guessing what you want accomplishing and it looks/is more probable that both chart elements to be modified proportionally:

```
Sub testActiveChartDimensions()
  Dim ch As Chart, plHeight As Double, plWidth As Double
  Set ch = ActiveChart 'plays with a selectded chart

  plHeight = ch.PlotArea.height: plWidth = ch.PlotArea.width 'memorize the plot area dimensions

  ch.Parent.height = ch.Parent.height * 2: ch.Parent.width = ch.Parent.width * 2 'resize the chartObject
  
  ch.PlotArea.height = plHeight: ch.PlotArea.width = plWidth 'reset the initial dimensions for plot area
                                                             ' you can set any other dimensions (just to be lower than the new chart dimensions...)
  ch.PlotArea.Position = xlChartElementPositionAutomatic     'center it on the chart object
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, this is the correct answer to the problem stated. I had followed every single step (locking in the height variables for the plot area and the chart) but did not think to reset the plotarea position automatically. Thank you so much.

Comment: I downvoted your answer by mistake. If you make some minor edit to your question then I will be able to change that to upvote. Right now it's locked until you edit your answer.

Comment: @Noobster No problem, it may happen... I will edit it, but if you do not find some time to come back, it will not be a problem, at all. I do not care too much about notoriety. I tried explaining in a comment about what is to be done and tried putting it in a piece of code, not being sure that I was clear enough. Anyhow, glad I could help!

Comment: @Noobster I'm confused,  how is this the answer.  OP states _... the plot area is automatically resized, which is an undesired outcome._ So I assume you want the Plot area to remain at its original size.  For me (using Excel 365) changing `.PlotArea.Position = xlChartElementPositionAutomatic` also changes the plot area size to fill the chart

Comment: @chris neilsen Nop... Using `.PlotArea.Position = xlChartElementPositionAutomatic` **after setting the `PlotArea` old dimensions** it only **centers** the `PlotArea` inside the `chartObject`.

Comment: @fane what version are you using?   As I said, in In 365 it also resizes (not what I'd expect from the name of the method, but it does)

Comment: @chris neilsen I am using Excel Mondo 2016 (Version 2201, build 14827.20192). I thought that the behavior is similar in all versions... Let me test it on Excel 2007. I have it installed on another computer...

Comment: @chris neilsen Tested in Excel 2017 and it behaves exactly in the same way. Running the code line by line, I can see the chart object dimensions being increased, then the new `PlotArea` dimensions being set, but not centered, being centered after the last code line... I tested it on 2DColumn chart type. I'm curious, now: What kind of chart did you try the code on?

Comment: I tested on a line chart, and your exact code.  It wouldn't be the first time MS introduced a bug between versions

Comment: @chris neilsen It may be an explanation... :) I tested the code on a line chart and it behaves as it should. Or, how it behaves on the other types on my installations...